# Return a list from Table-Valued SQL Function in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, wcf

I have a WCF service using Entity Framework 6 (`_Context`) which successfully calls a number of functions in my SQL db however, I am having issues calling a table-valued function.

My function takes a single string parameter `user` and creates a view using a `where` clause to determine what that user can see. This works as expected e.g:

```
SELECT * FROM ises.fnarticles ('ANDREW')
```

I am now trying to call the function from my WCF service and return results to a list:

```
  public List<vwArticle> GetArticlesByAnalyst(string user)
    {
         return ((IObjectContextAdapter)_Context).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<vwArticle>("SELECT VALUE ISESModel.Store.fnarticles(@userName) FROM {1}", 
         new ObjectParameter("userName", user)).ToList();
    }
```

I am getting the error:

```
{"The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord]' type to the 'IsesServiceModel.vwArticle' type is not valid."}
```

I can't return a list nor a single vwArticle object for that matter. Same error...

Answer (score 0):

This method is long winded but achieved what I needed. Seems like you can use LINQ to query a tabled value function as though it's a table...

```
public List<vwArticle> GetArticlesByAnalyst(string user)
    {
        List<vwArticle> ArticlesByAnyalist = new List<vwArticle>();

        var query = from a in _Context.fnarticles(user)
                    select a;

        foreach (var a in query)
        {
            var article = new vwArticle
            {
                ArticleId = a.ArticleId,
                ArticleTitle = a.ArticleTitle,
                Country = a.Country,                   
                userUpdated = a.userUpdated,
                userCreated = a.userCreated,
                dateCreated = a.dateCreated,
                dateUpdated = a.dateUpdated,
                versionDate = a.versionDate    
            };

            ArticlesByAnyalist.Add(article);
        }

        return ArticlesByAnyalist;
    }
```

And then invoke my method passing in the username & querying the list:

```
    public List<vwArticle> GetArticles(string filter)
    {
      var ArticlesByAnalyst = GetArticlesByAnalyst("GEMMA");

      var query = from a in ArticlesByAnalyst 
                  where blah blah                        
                  select a;

      return query.ToList();  
    }
```